# What happens if I upload a report using a .pbix file and then make changes to the report in Power BI Service? Will those changes be overwritten?

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI report that I've created in Power BI Desktop.  I save the report to a .pbix file and upload the report to Power BI Service using the .bpix file stored in SharePoint/OneDrive.

If I make changes to the report visuals in Power BI Service, will those changes be overwritten by OneDrive refresh of the visuals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, once changes have been made to the report in the service, it will not write back to the OneDrive file. To get those changes, you have to export the PBI Report out of the service and resave it. If you reload the PBI report again before exporting your changes, it will overwrite anything that you have done in the service.

Comment: Thank you!  Do you have and links to further documentation on this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-upload-desktop-files It doesn't fully give you an example, if you do a search, there are a few more example on reddit and blogs